# I want Date Like 21-Sep-12 in Sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have searched but i havent get the format like 21-Sep-12 date format in sql.I get every other format but i didnt get this type of Format.so,How can i get the format like this in Date?

Comment: Do you want to show date in this format?

Comment: what type of database server is used? besides, the interface that reads data should format dates (default is the operating system settings) you can use special date formatter to output dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should rather do teh formatting on the UI/Report side.

Why do you need in in this format?

But if you must, try

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), GETDATE(), 6), ' ', '-') AS [DD-Mon-YY]
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4587/0)

[Here is a nice list of formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: I always find that SQL Server's date formatting capabilities are really **way** too complicated (compared to e.g. `to_char(current_date, 'dd-mon-yy')` in PostgreSQL or Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - SQL Server 2012 has a more straightforward [`FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), GETDATE(), 6), ' ', '-') AS [DD-Mon-YY]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Declare @dt datetime=getdate()
 select REPLACE(convert(varchar(20),@dt,6),' ','-')
```